# Auto resize an area created with a script

Tags: javascript, autoresize

At first I'm not a programmer but in some way handy to adjust code. Not always succesfull. :-)

I've got the following javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
         src='http://knvbwidget.sportlink.com/widget_js.php?soort=team-liggend&clubcode=xxxxxxx&height=1000&width=800'> 
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    showWidget();
</script>
```

It display's the result of a soccerteam in a certain format. As you can see you can set the height and with.

I would like to have this autosized in particular the height.
Is this possible?

I use this script in a Wordpress page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would then investigate the resulting document element(s). If e.g. some classes (lets say `class="widget"`) or ids are added to the elements, you can add CSS code that modifies the behavior of those elements. e.g.

```
.widget {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```